# Decision procedure vs Proof system in Predicate Logic

Tags: predicate-logic

I recently started reading [Logic in Computer Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052154310X) and in section 2.5 the authors talk about decision procedures. They state in Theorem 2.22, "The decision problem of validity in predicate logic is undecidable: no program exists which, given any $\phi$, decides whether $\models \phi$". But from my understanding $\models \phi \rightarrow \vdash \phi$ by the completeness theorem, and you can show is  $\vdash \phi$ is a theorem by using analytic tableaux (a proof procedure not present in this book) which is (in my understanding) an algorithmic procedure. It seems that this is a contradiction! So obviously I'm missing some important piece of information. I'd really appreciate if someone could clear this up.

Answer (score 2):

The method of tableaux is a proof procedure that, when applied to a valid formula $X$ (i.e. starting the tableaux with $FX$), produce in a finite number of steps a closed tableaux (i.e. a tableaux showing that $FX$ is *unsatisfiable*), i.e. a proof of the formula.

But **if** the formula is not *vaid*, you can go on forever without closing it. Thus, the proof procedure is not a decision method because we have no way to know in advance (in the general case) if a formula of f-o logic is valid or not (a f-o "version" of truth table may involve an infinite number of cases to be managed).

Comment: Perfect answer thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

When you state that $\models\phi\implies\vdash\phi$, this is for propositional logic - that is, without quantifiers.  Yes, there is a decision procedure for propositional logic.  However, predicate logic involves quantifiers.  This type of logic has no decision procedure.